# how pass parameter usin soap web services in ios app

Tags: ios, soap

This is my first application to call soap services. generally i am use php service.please any one help to how to call soap service and how to pass parameter using soap service in ios
.

Comment: This question as-is is much too broad to be answered reasonably. You might want to search the web for a tutorial or the manual

Answer (score 0):

Giving pythonic way for tax-web page (should be similiar to php only  libs will be different):

```
import suds
from suds.client import Client

client = Client("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl")
result = client.service.checkVat('GB', '11120021' )
```

In wsdl file you will always find which parameters you should feed to get back result